# can I call dropdownlist selectedIndexchanged before PageLoad event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When changing the value in `dropdownlist`. `selectedIndexchange` should call before `PageLoad` event.

How can I call `dropdownlist` `selectedIndexchanged` before `PageLoad` event?

Comment: IHMO, Firstly search more about your doubts you will get somewhere then fire a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373885/handle-event-before-page-load
Now, Before diving into asp, its better if you can understand the ASP.NET Page Life Cylce.

Answer (score 2):

as per `ASP.NET` `Life cycle` `Page_Load` Event Fires first and then the other `control` events will be fired.

but you can fire the `dropDownList` `SelectedIndexChanged` event by calling `SelectedIndexChanged` event manually from `Page_Load` event handling code as a first step.

Try This:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //call the DropDownList1 selectedindexchanged event manually
        dropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);

       //page load event handling code

}

protected void dropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //DropDownList1 SelectedIndexChanged event handling code.
}
```

Comment: Make sure to pass `dropdownList1` instead of `sender` from the `Page_Load` to avoid potential casting error in the `dropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` event.